# how to show stencil JS build on html without localhost?

Tags: html, typescript, stenciljs

How to show stencil JS build on html without localhost ?
It is running on local server but I want only running the html file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNkZR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you may have tried using the files directly from your local machine. This wont work because it will be blocked by CORS issue. Stencil has a lot of requests to load files to your browser when you use the webcomponet.

Possible Solution.
If all scripts can be bundled in to a single javascript file then it will be possible to use this without hosting.